# How do I use the Hive "test in(val1, val2)" built in function?

Tags: hadoop, hive

The Programming Hive book lists a `test in` built in function in Hive, but it is not obvious how to use it and I've been unable to find examples

Here is the information from Programming Hive:

```
Return type   Signature                Description
-----------   ---------                -----------
BOOLEAN       test in(val1, val2, …)   Return true if testequals one of the values in the list.
```

I want to know if it can be used to say whether a value is in a Hive array.

For example if I do the query:

```
hive > select id, mcn from patients limit 2;
id              mcn
68900015        ["7382771"]
68900016        ["8847332","60015163","63605102","63251683"]
```

I'd like to be able to test whether one of those numbers, say "60015163" is in the mcn list for a given patient.

Not sure how to do it.

I've tried a number of variations, all of which fail to parse.  Here are two examples that don't work:

```
select id, test in (mcn, "60015163") from patients where id = '68900016';
select id, mcn from patients where id = '68900016' and test mcn in('60015163');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not `test in` bu instead `in`. In the table 6-5 `test` is a colum name.
So in order to know whether a value is in a Hive array, you need first to use `explode` on your array.
Instead of explode the array column, you can create an UDF, as it is explain here http://souravgulati.webs.com/apps/forums/topics/show/8863080-hive-accessing-hive-array-custom-udf-

Comment: Looks like you're right. This is just the standard "IN" clause for an SQL WHERE clause.  It's just documented in a very poor manner.  Also, I'm using explode with LATERAL VIEW and it's working well, so thanks for the answer.